# Maintain apect ratio of youtube video using video.js

Tags: css, html, youtube, youtube-api

I am using a html5 video tag for playing youtube video. I am facing the problem of aspect ratio. I am unable to remove black bars from the youtube video.

```
> <video id="vjs-youtube" height="385" width="710" class="video-js
> vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" poster=""  x-webkit-airplay="allow"
> data-setup='{"techOrder":"youtube","html5"],"ytcontrols":false}'>
> <source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BS-PEEAgNk"
> type="video/youtube"></source> </video>
```

Appreciate any suggestions,

Answer (score 1):

Try out this,

**Html**

```
 <video id="discovery" src="discovery.mp4"></video>
```

**JavaScript**

```
  var videoelement = document.getElementById("discovery");
  videoelement.videoHeight; // returns the intrinsic height of the video
  videoelement.videoWidth; // returns the intrinsic width of the video
```

Source (HTML5 spec): http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#video

You can then calculate the aspect ratio by dividing the width by the height.

I hope this helps.